# whitelist firebase functions in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-functions

Have an API done in firebase functions where I'm trying to connect to MSSQL but the firewall on the server is using a whitelist which make it difficult. I can not find my firebase functions IP(to add to whitelist) and attempt to ping URL was unsuccessful as well (getting error "ping request could not find host"). Any suggestions?

Comment: Cloud Functions doesn't have a static IP address.  You can expect that it might change over time, without warning.

Comment: ok, understand that but is there any solution for my case...?

Comment: Did you read the duplicate?

Comment: now I did - sorry for that, will give it a try('next level' -thing going on there) - ty for your help sir (y)